# How to get the order of the sorted rows in plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plupload

I have a requirement where I need to sort the rows of the plupload. I added the code `(sortable : true)` and now it is working. Now I want to know the order of the sorting.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. As far as I know, your uploader.files property will be reordered to reflect what appears in the UI. Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: @jbl yes you are correct. But i want that order in numbers. Take example like i have uploaded 4 files (order 1234) then i am rearranging 1 to 4 then now my new order is(order 2341).This numbers only i exactly want.

Answer (score 2):

You may try, on FilesAdded, to add a `initialIndex` property to the files object. And query this property later on the files objects to know which ordering has been performed.

Assuming `uploader` is :

```
var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
```

then

```
    // add initialIndex property on new files, starting index on previous queue size
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up,files){
         for(var i = 0, upPreviousSize = up.files.length - files.length, size = files.length; i<size; i++)
          {
              files[i]["initialIndex"] = i +upPreviousSize ;
          }
          //console.log(up.files);
        });


    // remove the 'holes' in the sequence when removing files 
    // (if not, next files adding would introduce duplicate initialIndex)
uploader.bind('FilesRemoved', function(up,files){
         // process removed files by initialIndex descending
         var sort = function(a,b){return b.initialIndex - a.initialIndex;};
         files.sort(sort);
         for(var i = 0, size = files.length; i<size; i++)
          {
            var removedFile = files[i];
            // update the remaining files indexes
            for (var j =0, uploaderLength = up.files.length; j<uploaderLength; j++)
            {
            var remainingFile = up.files[j];
            if(remainingFile["initialIndex"] >  removedFile["initialIndex"])
                remainingFile["initialIndex"]--;
            }
          }           
          //console.log(up.files);
        });
```

Comment: I trying to achieve this.I will update you tomorrow morning thanks for your help @jbl

Answer (score 0):

If using the Plupload 2.1 jQuery UI widget:

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function (up, file) {
  var index = $('#uploader_filelist li').index($('#' + file.id));
});
```